# How to send received byte array file in a continuous flow to another API in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, stream, axios, buffer

I have to send the received file (in byte array format) to another API which will store it physically. What I have done so far is that, I have obtained the file byte chunks on data event of request and adding it to chunks array and when the data obtained fully I concatenated and created a Buffer and then simply send this buffer data to another API using `axios` put method.

```
export const putProduct: RequestHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const chunks: Uint8Array[] = [];
    req.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
    req.on('end', async () => {
        try {
            const data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            const response = await axios.put("REMOTE_API_URL", data);
            return res.status(response.status).send(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.data);
        }
    });
};
```

This is working fine and the physically file stored on the remote API endpoint successfully.

Now the problem with this approach is that it will create a huge amount of performance overhead as these chunks will be stored in an array (in memory) and if the file size is huge then it will cost ample amount of memory to hold it.

What I want is to send the individual byte chunks in a continuous flow as we are receiving it on data event of request. I found that `axios` don't have such support. Suggestion about any library which can do this or any other approach which will be feasible to tackle this situation will be a great help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A novel solution would be to use sockets. Create a single socket(singleton pattern) and then stream it to the other API since your receiving the data in chunks in a continuous pattern. I am not sure what architecture your using but you could also use, AWS SQS and lambda. Just put the chunks in SQS and then using Lambda which would trigger once chunk is added into the Queue. It will store the chunk where is needed.

Comment: Hey, @HassanAbbas thanks for the suggestion. But I am stuck with the current approach due to some security issues and requirement. Is there any way out other than what you have mentioned? Or can you provide the socket example what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Posting my own answer as it worked for me.

We can simply pass the request object as it is to axios put/post method if we are receiving data in binary format. This will provide a solution to the problem of huge amount memory consumption, which was caused by the chunk array previously as the express request object is itself a stream it will not cause any memory overhead.

```
export const putProduct: RequestHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.put("REMOTE_API_URL", req);
        return res.status(response.status).send(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.data);
    }
};
```